Issue with jsPDF and AutoTable: "Error generating PDF: RangeError: Invalid string length at Array.join" when adding too many images
I'm using jsPDF with the AutoTable plugin to generate PDFs that include a large number of images. However, when there's too much data (specifically, images), I encounter the error:
Error generating PDF: RangeError: Invalid string length at Array.join

I've narrowed the issue down to the following code block where images are added:
doc.addImage(imgSrc,
    textPos.x + (data.cell.padding('horizontal') / 2),
    textPos.y + (data.cell.padding('vertical') / 2),
    dim_width,
    dim, 
    imgAlias,
    'FAST');

It seems that when the total concatenated imgSrc (which contains all the image URLs) becomes too long, the PDF fails to generate or save correctly.
If I remove the imgAlias parameter from addImage(), the PDF generates successfully without the "string is too long" issue, but the problem is that all the rows in the table display the same image, rather than the relevant image for each row.
How can I solve this issue in a manner where it wouldn't occur again? Even if the image src URL were to be further shortened, it will still eventually reach the maximum string length resulting in this issue occuring again.
<table id="image-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($cvData as $index => $data)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $index }} - {{ $data->id }}</td>
                <td>
                    <img 
                    src="{{ env('IMG_URL') . '/' . $data->image_url }}" 
                    class="lazyload" 
                    alt="Image" 
                    crossorigin="anonymous">
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

doc.autoTable({
    html: table,
    theme: 'grid',
    startY: 15,
    rowPageBreak: 'avoid',
    styles: { cellPadding: 2, fontSize: 10, rowPageBreak:'avoid', minCellHeight:10},
    didParseCell: async function(cell, opts) {
        console.log("Parsing");
        if (cell.cell.section === 'body') {
            var td = cell.cell.raw;
            if (td !== undefined) {
                var img = td.getElementsByTagName('img');
                if (img.length > 0) {
                    cell.cell.styles.minCellHeight = 30;
                    cell.cell.contentHeight = 30;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    didDrawCell: function(data) {
        console.log("Drawing");
        if (data.cell.section === 'body') {
            var td = data.cell.raw;
            if (td !== undefined) {
                var img = td.getElementsByTagName('img');
                if (img.length > 0) {
                    var dim = data.cell.height - data.cell.padding('vertical');
                    var dim_width = data.cell.width - data.cell.padding('horizontal');
                    var textPos = data.cell;
                    var imgSrc = img[0].src;


                    var imgAlias = "img-"+imageIndex
                    console.log("imgSrc = " +imgSrc);
                    console.log("imgAlias = " +imgAlias);
                    doc.addImage(imgSrc,
                        textPos.x + (data.cell.padding('horizontal')/2),
                        textPos.y + (data.cell.padding('vertical')/2),
                        dim_width,
                        dim, 
                        imgAlias,
                        'FAST');

                    imageIndex ++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});


Many systems have limited lengths of string some as short as 8 characters but they have a limit for a reason and thus that limit whatever it is cannot be broken. The answer is dont use strings but a binary stream, as those can be as big as a buffer or Many GB if a file. The same is true for a canvas thus many systems can only split such methods into a few pages but not when say 12 or 20
